# How could I write a traversal query in neo4j (gremlin/cypher either one)?

Tags: database, neo4j, traversal, tree-traversal

Perferbly gremlin, but either one will do;

I am storing nodes in a database that form tree like structures.
example: /dir/inside_dir/alaskan-natives/story1

Nodes are attached with a relationship called **HAS_CHILD_NODE** (if it would be more efficient to add properties to each relationship to speed up the query or make it more logical please inform me of this).
Each node can only have one parent association. In **one** query - removing all *looping* from my application its self - how do I **traverse** down each *path* only to obtain specified ones until we have reached our *end result.*

Well assume I've already spliced at the '/' and now we have an array of hierarchal items we can attach to a query.

```
var array = ['dir', 'inside_dir', 'alaskan-natives', 'story1'];
```

Remember this must be a ***dynamic query*** allowing any amount of items to be traversed down the tree and consist of an ability to interchange hierarchal names. Try and optimize it please.

Just a simple tree to help in understanding; it is not related to my situation.
[image: Please view this tree example]

Comment: To me, it's unclear what you are asking, can you state your question better?

Comment: Simply put, I want to follow down through related nodes.  start with "dir", find a relationship from "dir" to "inside_dir"; once found, then continue from "inside_dir" to a node with the name "alaskan-natives" with a relationship to inside_dir and so forth until we have the last item. So we are going from 'dir' -> 'inside_dir' -> 'alaskan-natives' -> 'story1' then retrive the data of story one and its properties.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is possible in Gremlin, look at the `loop` pipe as I've accomplished similar answers with this.

Comment: Nick, I'm going to look into Gremlin and let you know what I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covered on the mailing list for Neo4j, https://groups.google.com/group/neo4j/

Comment: Mind sharing the actual message link? =)

Comment: Please can you share the actual link?